# android app making native calls without native library

Tags: android, native, frida

im reversing this android app for fun and to learn about android ndk so
im running this app on a x86 android studio emulator and the app did not include any x86 shared librarys it only included arm libs yet the app is still making native calls somehow?? when i inspect the modules loaded by the app i dont find any libs from the lib folders i only find this weird .odex file?
i tried loading the libs using frida `Process.loadModule('lib.so')` but i get a dlopen error
i used ghidra to decompile the arm librarys now will i be able to compile what i got from ghidra back to x86 .so librarys?
and if a app has a native method and it dosent have a lib implementing that method then what will happen if we call the native java method?? will it throw a error?

edit: i know its making native calls because i tried hooking a native method thats being called and its returning a string? how can this be possible?
i know that android 11 runing on android studio emulator can translate arm binaries to x86 then still why arent the libs loaded into memory and why cant i hook then using frida-trace?

Comment: Are you sure the app doesn't contains any native libraries? Any file in the APK file can be a native library, not only files in the standard native library path can be loaded. It is also possible that native libraries are included in obfuscated form and transformed before they are loaded. And last libraries can also be downloaded.

Comment: @Robert im not sure but how will i find these obfuscated native librarys? and why dont they show up in the loaded modules?

Comment: Another possibility is that your emulator is one of those that have the new ARM emulation integrated. If I remember correctly some of the API 30 emulators do include such an emulation layer so that they can use ARM libraries even if the emulator is x86. Regarding obfuscated libraries you can only find them by tracing the app and check their file operations.

Comment: @Robert yes i already said in my question the new android 11 have arm translation and native library is being loaded yet i cant hook it using frida